# Google App Engine for PHP での Bigtable

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Google App Engine for PHP から Bigtable にアクセスできますか？

GAEに経験の無い初心者です。
稚拙な無いようですが、よろしくお願い致します。

試験的で比較的小規模なアプリケーションを作成するにあたって、デバイス間のデータ同期が必要になり、Bigtableを使用したいと考えています。

Java等も書けないことないのですが、どちらかというと勘がはたらくPHPでサクッと作れると嬉しいのでGoogle App Engine for PHPを選択しました。
一見、PHPで利用できるのは「Google Cloud SQL」だけのようですが「Bigtable」は利用できないのでしょうか？（Google Cloud SQLは無料枠があるか理解できなかった）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DatastoreのことをBigTableと呼ばれているのだと仮定して回答いたします。

AppEngine for PHPではDatastoreに直接アクセスすることはできないようです。
また、Cloud SQLに無料枠はないようです。

ただし、JSON APIを通してDatastoreを利用することはできるようです。

---

ご参考

- [Storing Data in PHP - PHP — Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/storage)
- [Google Cloud SQL - SQL サーバー、クラウド データベース、オンライン データベース — Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/sql/?hl=ja#pricing)
- [Sign Up - Google Cloud Datastore — Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#accessing_an_existing_app_engine_datastore_from_another_platform)